# How to plot rectangles of equal width onto a map in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have global population data on two related metrics, and would like to make mini bar plots for each location on the map. Since I only need two bars per population, and they all have a similar scale, I was planning to just plot them using geom_rect(). However, the bar widths aren't consistent, even between the two bars for the same population.
[image]

Here's the simplified R code I used for this:

```
library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_bw())
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
library("rgeos")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

pop_data <- data.frame(long=c(-63,-68,-108,86,64,129,114,174,143,90,64,-21,40,-4,38.7),
                   lat=c(-23,3,29,51,64,63,32,-41,-4,24,26,64,61,40,39),
                   measA=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10),
                   measB=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10))
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf()+
  geom_rect(data = pop_data,fill="blue",
            aes(xmin = long-2,
                xmax = long-1,
                ymin = lat,
                ymax = lat+measA))+
  geom_rect(data = pop_data,fill="red",
            aes(xmin = long+1,
                xmax = long+2,
                ymin = lat,
                ymax = lat+measB))+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

The bars will be different heights in the final plot, but this is just to illustrate the width differences. Can anyone explain why the widths differ, and how to resolve this issue? I'm also open to other solutions for making simple mini bar plots on a map. I did see other solutions for making mini bar plots, but most of them use a ggplot function that no longer works.

Comment: This may turn out to be a silly follow-up question but... Do you observe the difference in width when you render the graphic with, let's say Rstudio, or when you save it as image? I run your code and, while the Rstudio render did show the problems you are referring to, the pdf version did not show any observable difference in the columns' widths.

Comment: @davidnortes is right - this is almost certainly only a problem with the RStudio graphics device - pdf export is crisp and everything has the right width.

Comment: Originally I just exported from the Rstudio render, but if I use jpeg() or png() instead to generate the image, I'm still seeing some width differences (though it's not as noticeable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you could choose a geom that draws a line and control the width via `size=` instead - it might make things look a bit more consistent for you.  As others mentioned, try exporting with different graphics, because the renderer for `jpeg()`, `png()` and `pdf()` may differ.  Here are two examples with `geom_segment()` and `geom_linerange()`.  Note that I would suggest taking your `pop_data` dataframe and gathering/melting/pivot_longer...ing the `measA` and `measB` columns together in order to simplify your `ggplot()` calls and avoid duplication of geoms.  You'll see I do that with `geom_linerang()`, but due to [dodging not working correctly with geom_segment](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3617), I show that one without modifying `pop_data`.

#### geom_segment()

```
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_segment(
    data=pop_data, color='blue',
    aes(x= long-1, xend=long-1, y= lat, yend=lat+measA),
    size=1.2) +
  geom_segment(
    data=pop_data, color='red',
    aes(x= long+1, xend=long+1, y= lat, yend=lat+measB),
    size=1.2) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

#### geom_linerange() with gathering of pop_data

As mentioned, I modify `pop_data` here using `dplyr` and `tidyr::gather()`, then only need one call to `geom_linerange()`.  I like this solution better, but result is quite similar:

```
pop_data1 <- pop_data %>%
  gather('measure', 'pop', -c(long,lat))

ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_linerange(
    data=pop_data1,
    aes(x= long, ymin= lat, ymax=lat+pop,
      color=measure, group=measure),
    size=1.2, position=position_dodge(5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red','blue')) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image]